# Documentation on which OCaml standard library function can raise which error

Tags: exception, ocaml, system-calls

The title says it all already—well *almost*:)

In particular, I'm interested in the functions in modules `Sys` and `Unix`.

The "Unix system programming in OCaml" book ([available here](https://ocaml.github.io/ocamlunix/)) states:

> #### 1.3  Error handling
>
> Unless otherwise indicated, all functions in the Unix module raise the exception `Unix_error` in case of error.
>
> `exception Unix_error of error * string * string`
>
> [...]
>
> Finally, the first argument of the exception is an error code indicating the nature of the error. It belongs to the variant type error:
>
> `type error = E2BIG | EACCES | EAGAIN | ...  | EUNKNOWNERR of int`

So far, so good, *but* ... *which* function can raise *which* `error`?

Which ones can, say, raise `Unix_error(EAGAIN,_,_)` and which ones can't?

Do I have to look into the implementation or is there a readily available list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml is just passing along the Unix error. The possible errors for each operation are in the Unix documentation. In fact this is documented reasonably well on the Unix-like systems I use. You can try `man 2 chmod` from the command line, for example.

However, the possible causes of each error (the inverse relation) is not documented so well (or at all) in my experience.